# How to make a list to be a list in a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have a list that is outputed from a function.

```
a = ['NO YES NO NO', 'YES YES NO YES', 'NO NO YES NO', ]
```

I want it to change to a input like this for another function .

```
a = [['YES', 'YES', 'NO', 'YES'],
['YES', 'NO', 'NO', 'YES'],
['NO', 'YES', 'NO', 'YES']]
```

ignore they are different elements.
How would I do that in Python 3.2 ?

Comment: `a = [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]` ? I don't understand your question. Please be more specific.

Comment: How did you want the grouping to take place? Every 4 elements? Or when the elements in one group are only increasing numbers? Do you have more examples or a better description?

Comment: well , the output of my function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> a = ['NO YES NO NO', 'YES YES NO YES', 'NO NO YES NO', ]
>>> [s.split() for s in a]
[['NO', 'YES', 'NO', 'NO'], ['YES', 'YES', 'NO', 'YES'], ['NO', 'NO', 'YES', 'NO']]
```

Comment: [<map object at 0x000000000356FF60>, <map object at 0x000000000356FFD0>, <map object at 0x0000000003572278>] is returned